# Assigning values for the custom setting object using visualforce page?

Tags: customsetting, visualforce

I am trying to insert values to the field in custom settings via visual force page

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="sample" sidebar="false" > <apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock >
        <apex:inputText value="{!myValueFromPage}"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!sample}" value="Save Input"/>
       </apex:pageblock> </apex:form> </apex:page>
```

Class:

```
public class sample
{
public String myValueFromPage{get; set;}

public void sample() {
User user = [Select Id from User where Name='warner'];
    garage_app__saver__c settings = garage_app__saver__c.getInstance();
    settings.name = myValueFromPage;
   settings.SetupOwnerId=user.Id;
    insert settings;
}



}
```

I am getting the following error

> > Error:
>
> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: SetupOwnerId (id
>   value of incorrect type): [SetupOwnerId]

I want to know where I am going wrong..Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the type of custom setting ?

Comment: Its of List type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
 CustomerSetting__c settings = CustomerSetting__c.getInstance();
    settings.SomeInfo__c = 'test';
    settings.name = 'test';
    settings.SetupOwnerId  = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
insert settings;
```

OR your code could be written like:

```
garage_app__saver__c settings = garage_app__saver__c.getInstance();
settings.name = myValueFromPage;
settings.SetupOwnerId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();;
insert settings;
```

Interestingly SFDC documentation says its USER ID (hirachy type setting) but it does not work when we pass USER ID.

> If no custom setting data is defined in the hierarchy, the returned
>   custom setting has empty fields, except for the SetupOwnerId field
>   which contains the user ID.
>   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm

To find the solution I just entered data via UI and queried it with workbench.

Then i realized it is ORG ID and not USER ID.

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: Please check if my answers solves the problem?